# convert list to strings by iterating resource with variable

Tags: terraform

Trying to convert list to strings by iterating resource with variable using if condition

How to use if condition for resource to iterate on variable(list) in for_each

```
locals {

  new_out = flatten([
    for opi, clsan in var.module_cl_list : {

      opic_R_P = reverse(split("@", "${opi}"))[1]
      #op_R = ["WRITE"]
      op_R = ["READ","DESCRIBE"]
      

    }
  ])  

}
```

for "Write" it is working, because resource takes one value per variable at a time

```
resource "something" "some" {


for_each  = {for opi1, clsa1 in local.new_out: opi1 => clsa1}

name = local.new_out_opic_R_P
op_R = join(", ", each.value.op_R)
permission = "ALLOW"
}
```

for resource if we want to iterate the op_R variable, ["READ","DESCRIBE"], How to convert list to string iteratively?

Input

if input variable is write only, variable should be assigned as write
if input variable is Read only, variable should be assigned itereatively with "READ" and "Describe"

note: WO = WRITE, RO = READ and DESCRIBE
**Example** :-

```
west = {
   name = "random1"
   operation = "WRITE"
   permission = "ALLOW"
},
west2 = {
   name = "random2"
   operation = "READ"
   permission = "ALLOW"
},
west2 = {
   name = "random2"
   operation = "DESCRIBE"
   permission = "ALLOW"
}
```

Current code works with this variable
op_R = ["WRITE"]

If given below variable, It fails to process i need this to do in iterative manner

**op_R = ["READ","DESCRIBE"]**

Input

module_cl_list = {

```
"west@WO" = {appid = "456"},
"west2@RO" = {appid = "123"}
```

}

Error

Current code taking value as "Read, Describe" , resource takes only one value at a time for each variable

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code? Any errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: Sadly its not clear what do you want to do. What is `var.module_cl_list`?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, i confuse my question, mentioned input  in description, I just want to convert list to string iteratively, currently its throwing with error "string required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double for loop:

```
  new_out = flatten([
    for opi, clsan in var.module_cl_list : [
      for op in (split("@", "${opi}")[1] == "RO" ? ["READ","DESCRIBE"] : ["WRITE"]): {
      opic_R_P = reverse(split("@", "${opi}"))[1]
      op_R = op
     } 
    ]
  ])
```

which will produce:

```
[
  {
    "op_R" = "READ"
    "opic_R_P" = "west2"
  },
  {
    "op_R" = "DESCRIBE"
    "opic_R_P" = "west2"
  },
  {
    "op_R" = "WRITE"
    "opic_R_P" = "west"
  },
]
```